# Json data from phpMyAdmin doesn't update on website

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what's happening but after I insert new data in mySQL database and I go to my website link that has that JSON data, it shows old json data. I have to clear my browser cached in order to see new data. Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue? I check my link with Postman and my json data does update everytime I test with it. Below is my code

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Comment: Just extra from copy and paste. I just edited my post.

Comment: This is not the whole code? Your having a closing bracket, the $result is never set. Show us some more pls

Comment: This has to do with the query caching of your DB. Check its settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can set headers to tell the browser not to cache the document and / or that the document has expired in the past:

```
...
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 2018 01:00:00 GMT");
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: my data works fine in Postman but on Chrome or Firefox, it doesn't update my data.